# How to implement a complete ZigBee stack(standard 802.15.4)

Tags: c#, zigbee

Hi guys for a project([jemma](http://github.com/ismb/jemma)) we are using ZigBee network for connecting devices to each other. We control these devices from pc and for connecting the pc to the ZigBee network we are using [FlexGrid](http://www.flexgrid.it/eng/prodotti/flexkey.html) dongle. But it's closed source so my main goal is use Waspmote gateway for replacing the FlexGrid.
So first of all I have written a class that manage serial port(layer 0) but now  I'm a bit confused. I've search around internet but I didn't find a guide that say to me hich path follow.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Why don't you use (Digi XBee Series 2) in API mode connected to your PC instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use Freescale's ZigBee stack.

Per the [FlexGrid datasheet](http://www.flexgrid.it/eng/pdf/flyer_key.pdf), "ZigBee capable with Freescale's BeeStack software stack".

Also, the [Jemma project technical specs](http://ismb.github.io/jemma/techs.html) says, "Modular structure for different hardware support; the Freescale MC13226V ZigBeePRO - USB module is actually developed".

I'd advise getting in touch with FlexGrid to see if they're aware of the Jemma project and whether their hardware (FlexGateway and FlexKey) is natively compatible with it.  If not, you can purchase USB dongles from Freescale with the MC13226 processor.

Interestingly, Freescale is [discontinuing the MC13226 and MC13224 products](http://cache.freescale.com/files/shared/doc/pcn/PCN15884.htm), so they might not be a good technology choice for your project.